# VBA Fill Variable Cell Range with Text Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to do the following (in title) using VBA in an excel macro.

I have found solutions on how to fill a set range with a value, however I cannot find anything relating to if the cell range to fill is a variable.

I wish to fill a column with text, but only until the last filled row (as the number of rows varies each day).

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: You should post the code you managed to write so far

Comment: Can't exactly post code for something I have not idea how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, see comments in code for more details.

```vb
Sub fillRange()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Name") '<-- set your sheet name
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

Dim rngToFill As Range 'declare the range variable
Set rngToFill = ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow) 'set the range variable

rngToFill.Value = "new value test" 'fill the range

End Sub
```